# Clarify what is safari classic mode?

Tags: safari, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-store

> My outlook add-in submission failed because my add-in doesn't load successfully in safari classic mode (as per email received from outlook validation team).
>   It is working nicely on safari Version 13.0.5.

Comment: We have raised your issue with the add-in validation team.

We recommend regular visits to the Office Dev Center  and to our forums to keep up-to-date with changes and common technical issues, as the validation team are unable to provide support for technical issues encountered during validation.

dev.office.com

Comment: Provide some solution regd. above issue. I checked on forum as well but I didn't find any satisfactory answer regd. this issue.

Comment: Please connect with office store validation team for any more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get clarification on how to test this also -- at least I think we're talking about the same thing. In our latest report from Microsoft, this is referred to as "Safari in Outlook Web App Classic mode." I've also seen the wording "classic experience."

My understanding is that this refers to a "classic" mode of Outlook, not of Safari. They happen to be testing it in Safari. We're able to get to the classic mode, or something like it, by going to this URL:

https://outlook.office.com/owa?path=classic

You'll see a different Outlook UI there. I don't think this is sufficient for really testing classic mode, because some of the links will take you back to the now-default UI.

Finally, we got past an issue that was worded as "not available to be loaded" by changing the minimum version of the requirement set specified in our add-in's manifest from 1.7 to 1.6. The symptom was that although you could add the add-in in classic mode, it didn't show up in the menu to use. Fortunately our add-in does work with 1.6. This doesn't seem quite right, but it does work, and might point you in the right direction.

On requirement sets and Outlook clients supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets